# HDFS distributed reads without Map/Reduce

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

Is it possible to achieve distributed reads from HDSF cluster using an HDFS client on one machine?

I have carried out an experiment with a cluster consisting of 3 data nodes (DN1,DN2,DN3). Then I run 10 simultaneous reads from 10 independent files from a client program located on DN1, and it appeared to be only reading data from DN1. Other data nodes (DN2,DN3) were showing zero activity (judging from debug logs).

I have checked that all files' blocks are replicated across all 3 datanodes, so if I shut down DN1 then data is read from DN2 (DN2 only).

Increasing the amount of data read did not help (tried from 2GB to 30GB).

Since I have a need to read multiple large files and extract only a small amount of data from it (few Kb), I would like to avoid using map/reduce since it requires settings up more services and also requires writing the output of each split task back to HDFS. Rather it would be nice to have the result streamed directly back to my client program from the data nodes.

I am using `SequenceFile` for reading/writing data, in this fashion (jdk7):

```java
//Run in thread pool on multiple files simultaneously

List<String> result = new ArrayList<>();
LongWritable key = new LongWritable();
Text value = new Text();
try(SequenceFile.Reader reader = new SequenceFile.Reader(conf,
                                     SequenceFile.Reader.file(filePath)){
  reader.next(key);
  if(key.get() == ID_I_AM_LOOKING_FOR){
    reader.getCurrentValue(value);
    result.add(value.toString());
  }
}

return result; //results from multiple workers are merged later
```

Any help appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm afraid the behavior you see is by-design. From [Hadoop document](http://hadoop.apache.org/hdfs/docs/current/hdfs_design.html#Data+Replication):

> > Replica Selection
> >
> > To minimize global bandwidth consumption and read latency, HDFS tries
> >     to satisfy a read request from a replica that is closest to the
> >     reader. If there exists a replica on the same rack as the reader node,
> >     then that replica is preferred to satisfy the read request. If angg/
> >     HDFS cluster spans multiple data centers, then a replica that is
> >     resident in the local data center is preferred over any remote
> >     replica.

It can be further confirmed by corresponding [Hadoop source code](https://github.com/apache/hadoop-hdfs/blob/trunk/src/java/org/apache/hadoop/hdfs/server/namenode/FSNamesystem.java#L887):

```java
  LocatedBlocks getBlockLocations(...) {
    LocatedBlocks blocks = getBlockLocations(src, offset, length, true, true);
    if (blocks != null) {
      //sort the blocks
      DatanodeDescriptor client = host2DataNodeMap.getDatanodeByHost(
          clientMachine);
      for (LocatedBlock b : blocks.getLocatedBlocks()) {
        clusterMap.pseudoSortByDistance(client, b.getLocations());

        // Move decommissioned datanodes to the bottom
        Arrays.sort(b.getLocations(), DFSUtil.DECOM_COMPARATOR);
      }
    }
    return blocks;
  }
```

I.e., all available replicas are tried one after another if former one fails but the nearest one is always the first.

On the other hand, if you access HDFS files through [HDFS Proxy](http://hadoop.apache.org/hdfs/docs/r0.21.0/hdfsproxy.html), it does pick datanodes [randomly](https://github.com/apache/hadoop-hdfs/blob/trunk/src/java/org/apache/hadoop/hdfs/server/namenode/FileDataServlet.java#L89). But I don't think that's what you want.

Comment: Thanks. That explains it! Thanks for the proxy tip.

Comment: How does Hadoop know which node is on which rack - http://hadoop.apache.org/common/docs/current/cluster_setup.html#Hadoop+Rack+Awareness

Comment: What is "angg"?

Answer (score 3):

In addition to what Edwardw said note that your current cluster is very small (just 3 nodes) and in this case you see the files on all the nodes. This happens because the default replication factor of Hadoop is also 3. In a larger cluster your files will not be available on each node and so accessing multiple files is likely to go to different nodes and spread the load.

If you work with smaller datasets you may want to look at HBase which lets you work with smaller chunks and spread the load between nodes (by splitting regions)

Comment: You are right. I've actually tried setting replication to 1 in attempt to distribute blocks evenly across the cluster, but it just ended up writing them all to DN1 :(( I guess I need more data and blocks before it starts balancing them out across different nodes. Thanks for the HBase tip, I can borrow some ideas from there.

Answer (score 0):

I would tell that your case sounds good for MR. If we put aside particular MR computational paradigm we can tell that hadoop is built to bring code to the data, instead of opposite. Moving code to the data is essential to get scalable data processing. 
In other hand - setting up MapReduce is easier then HDFS - since it store no state between jobs.
In the same time - MR framework will care about parallel processing for you - something it will take time to do properly.
Another point- if results of data processing is so small - there will be no significant performance impact if you will combine them together in reducer.
In other words - I would suggest to reconsider use of the MapReduce.

Comment: If you will drop me some information I will try to helo with estimations.

Comment: Thanks. It's pretty simple, basically a grep-like search on large file(s) of log data. Log data can be of arbitrary content. I have two types of search: 1) grep-like substring/regex matching on the content 2) seek to a known log position (positions/ids are stored separately) and just get the content. You can assume that the result set is always going to be small: 0~100 logs. Also I am using block compression (using `SequenceFile` API).

Comment: For the log data, it might be convinient to have some inrmalization layer in form of input formats. If you would like to reduce parsing / object creation overhead - you can do some filtering when reading data from the HDFS stream in the RecordReader. What are your performance requirements / expectations?